# How to create a complex table based on Data Validation and the sheet names

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I need to create a Spreadsheet that joins several information from different parts of the Sheets based on some rules. For example a

So I have 2 fixed sheets, that is table of procedures with its prices, that depends on the contract, example:

Sheet name: **Procedures - list and prices**

| Procedure | Private (R$) | MediPlan (R$) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ultrassound of abdomen | 100 | 80 |
| ultrassound of knee | 120 | 90 |

Second fixed table im going to explain after.

Than there is an undefined, and increasing number of Agenda Sheets. The tactics I use now is to name it by the date of the consultation. And as the time goes, there are created new copies of this agenda, renaming it always by date when it will take place.
It contains basically Name of the patient, Procedure to be done, Select of the Health plan, and a marker, if he showed up.

Sheet name: **05/03**

| Patient | Procedure | Health plan | Showed up |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jack | ultrassound of abdomen | Private | yes |
| Maria | ultrassound of abdomen | Private | no |
| Tom | ultrassound of knee | MediPlan | yes |

Coming back to a 2nd fixed sheet, let's call it Financial summary of the day.
I use a script, that enlists all sheets of the document and by Data Validation I intend to make you select the day of your interrest and create a list of all patients that showed up, listing their name, health plan, and price paid by the parient to the clinic. And here is where I need the help. I dont knoq, hot to create a call by the name of the sheet in the middle of the formula. And might be, that it actually needs a script, since not all the patients show up every time, so the ones that dont need to be excluded from the list to not pollute it. The result should be something like this:

Sheet name: **Financial overview**

| Patient | Procedure | Health plan | Price (R$) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jack | ultrassound of abdomen | Private | 100 |
| Tom | ultrassound of knee | MediPlan | 90 |

*Note: Leaving Maria out*

Any Idea of how to create this **Financial overview**?

Comment: At first, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Can I ask you about your question? 1. In your tags, `google-apps-script` and `google-sheets-formula` are included. Which method do you want to achieve your goal using? 2. About your tables, the most left side is the column "A"? And, the header row is the 1st row of the sheet? 3. In your situation, only 3 sheets like `Procedures - list and prices`, `05/03` and `Financial overview` are in a Google Spreadsheet?

Comment: 4. For example, when the existing rows in the sheets `Procedures - list and prices` and `05/03` are edited, what do you want to do? 5. For example, when the value of `Procedure` of `05/03` is not found at `Procedures - list and prices`, what do you want to do?

Comment: Hi Tanaike, I'm not an english native either, so my apologies as well :-) To comment your questions: 
1. If it would be possible to be solved through a formula, great. If it would need a script, than be it. The thing is I dont know the scrpt language, but Im able to read a code a bit since I'm using VBA, so if it would be to adjust some details, I would be able to, I hope, as long as it would be just a few details, like changing values, ranges etc. 
2. The table is actually a bit more complex, but doesnt have rellevant info for solving the task now, like a phone number of the patient, ...

Comment: ..., general observations, the `Procedures - list and prices` has now 6 price categories and might be increasing, `Procedures - list and prices` starts with header at A11:G11, the A column is the name of the porcedure, the rest are the different pricings of the procedure. 
Table `5/3` has these categories  `No. of pac.` | `Patient` | `Telephone` | `Procedure` | `Notes (about the procedure)` | `Health Plan` | `Confirmed Booking` | Procedure done` | `General Notes`, starting at  A8.

Comment: ... question 3 - everything is in one document of Google Sheets.
4. If `Procedures - list of prices` has alteration, it needs to project to `5/3`, but the `Financial overview` might be altered, but it's not essencial. If it does, ok, if it doesnt, fine as well. 
5. in the table `5/3` the data validation is done, so it requires a defined item of the procedure to match, so this case should not happen.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I could understand about the answers of Q1, Q4 and Q5. But I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about the answers of Q2 and Q3. About `The table is actually a bit more complex`, when the answerers propose an answer, that can be used for your sample in your question. But that might not be able to be used for your actual situation. I'm worry about this. I apologize for this.